# Intersection of two List<int[]> types by java streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
List<int[]> bigList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
List<int[]> smallList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

I need to generate a List of type int[] with the common arrays form both the lists.(values should be equal , not using the contains())

How to do it efficiently in java streams??

Comment: I don't understand why you are talking about streams. There's no stream here, just List and Array.

Comment: ofCourse no stream here, I need the stream implementation of this problem.

Comment: Why? Normally, you want a solution, perhaps an efficient one. But what’s the reason to insist on streams being involved in the solution? By the way, when you want an intersection, you should consider using `Set`s. Otherwise, you have define a lot more aspects of your task. How shall duplicates within the source lists be handled? Which order do you expect from the resulting list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it really has to be a stream solution, here’s one:

```
List<int[]> intersection=bigList.stream().map(IntBuffer::wrap)
    .filter(b->smallList.stream().map(IntBuffer::wrap).anyMatch(b::equals))
    .map(IntBuffer::array)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it isn’t really efficient by performing up to bigList.size()×smallList.size() operations. So instead of doing everything on-the-fly, resorting to an intermediate `Set` storage is strongly recommended:

```
Set<IntBuffer> bigSet=bigList.stream().map(IntBuffer::wrap).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<int[]> intersection=smallList.stream().map(IntBuffer::wrap)
     .filter(bigSet::contains).map(IntBuffer::array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you shouldn’t use `List` for set operations. The semantics of source and result ordering and how to handle duplicates within the source lists are unspecified.

Comment: thanks @Holger, duplication and ordering is not mentioned because duplication is already taken care and ordering doesn't matter.